# Pick specific commit from the another branch to the current one

Tags: git

I have created a new `branch-a` from the `master` and implemented new feature.

Right now I have created `branch-b` and I'd like to get one of the `branch-a` commits (which is not yet merged into `master`).
Is it possible to do the `cherry-pick` from the sibling branch ?

Comment: You could have found this information by **a)** trying **b)** reading the docs. I only tell you so you can avoid possible downvotes in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can `cherry-pick` everything that can be specified by [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

As stated in the [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) documentation:

> ```
> <commit>…​
> ```
>
> Commits to cherry-pick. For a more complete list of ways to spell commits, see gitrevisions[7]. Sets of commits can be passed but no traversal is done by default, as if the --no-walk option was specified, see git-rev-list[1]. Note that specifying a range will feed all …​ arguments to a single revision walk (see a later example that uses maint master..next).